# $(window).on('resize') in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, resize

In JavaScript, is the following code:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    // Do something.
}
```

The same as:

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    // Do something.
});
```

Are the two code blocks above equal, functionality-wise? Is there any advantage or disadvantage (however minor) using one or the other?

What about:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
    // Do something.
});
```

Comment: window.onresize is DOM $(window).on is jQuery. Both are different but the effect is same

Answer (score 31, accepted):

They aren't the same, in the first example, you're affecting an event to the dom object `onresize` handler.

The jQuery version is probably doing something different behind the scene. Without looking into the source code, it is probably simply doing:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {...})
```

That said, the jQuery version and the native `addEventListener` are still different because jQuery is also adding some magic to the event handler.

And `addEventListenener` is probably the prefered way to add event to a DOM object, because you can add multiple events but with the dom attribute `on[event]` you're limited to one event.

Here's a bit more about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

While you're at it, you could also read about the `addEventListener` friend: `removeEventListener`.

Comment: Plus the advantage of jQuery is a guarantee of cross browser compatibility. Not a big deal, if you only care about the newest browsers but really useful with the older ones.

Comment: @Anton that might be possible but I haven't wrote much anything using jQuery for a couple of years and I never felt better. Having to work with a properly organized framework is 9000 times nicer than working on a jQuery glued dom modifications, and even though `addEventListener` is longer to write, a properly done framework could prevent even creating any kind of event listener explicitely. Knowing the internals is good to move further.

Comment: Thanks Loïc and Anton for your answers. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Loïc Faure-Lacroix, considering any JS framework beside jQuery is out of the scope of this question. GTS Joe asked to compare those 3 approaches, that is it. As I said, if you care about older browser (e.g. IE 8) you would prefer the jQuery way. IE 8 for example does not support addEventListener at all - it uses the MS proprietary attachEvent method.That is why jQuery became so popular in the past years - you do not have to take care about browser differencies.I understand this pretty well as I resisted to using jQuery for a long time. Situation with new browsers is of course much better now.

Comment: Well in that case, if you need to support a 7 years old browser, you're still limited to jQuery 1.x (jQuery 2.x for IE9+). Considering other frameworks isn't out of the scope, there are a lot of good alternative that some people might not be aware of.

Answer (score 19):

No they are not same. You could try:

```
  $(window).on('resize',function1);
  $(window).on('resize',function2);
```

and function1 and function2 both respond when window resize.

But if you using

```
 window.onresize = function1;
 window.onresize = function2;
```

Only function2 respond.